# Wrong OData EntityContainer Schema Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, jaydata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I'm using ASP.NET MVC WebApi as OData service and I want to query this OData service with Jaydata.

Jaydata has a command line util (JaySvcUtil.exe) that downloads the service definition ($metadata) and creates a full featured JayData / JavaScript client environment by generating the necessary boilerplate code.

Web API + Odata is generating this $metadata page:
https://gist.github.com/3917081#file_metadata.xml

The WebApiConfig:
https://gist.github.com/3917081#file_web_api_config.cs

When i run

> JaySvcUtil.exe -m http://odataserver.com:52132/api/$metadata -o
>   Scripts/test.js -n Test.Testing

It will generate this javascript file
https://gist.github.com/3917081#file_jaydatafile.js

The problem is in the generated javascript file:

```
Default.context = new Default.Container( { name:'oData', oDataServiceHost: 'http://servername:52132/api' });
```

The namespace = "Default" because of the following value in the $metadata page.

```
Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm"
```

How can i change this namespace value in the  $metadata page or remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been supported in odata nightly build. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/353867

After you upgrade the package to latest signed build. You can change the namespace on the model builder.

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.Namespace = "xxx";
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<ProductionOrder>("ProductionOrders");
        return modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```